# I've typed the necessary code to display a background color but nothing is being displayed. Also I'm using sass

Tags: html, css, sass

Can someone please explain why the background color isn't displaying on my site?

This is my css

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: linear-gradient(#af67e9, #6565e7);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i did that and it still isn't working, so its not the css thats the issue

Answer (score 1):

A gradient is not a `background-color` - it's a `background` or `background image`.

Also the `body` needs content or a `height` to have a background on..

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(#af67e9, #6565e7);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
  height: 100vh;
}
```